# Manage Smartfox and Symfony2 sessions together

Tags: symfony, session, unity-game-engine, smartfoxserver

I've got an application with symfony for the backoffice and Unity3d for the front.

The front is a 3d game, and to manage multi-users we will use a SmartFox server.

I don't know how to use the session of SmartFox, and Symfony server together.

Everyone i've got an idea ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nobody 've got an idea ?